# getting illegal start of expression error

Tags: java

i'm totally new to java. i 'm try to create my first program & i get this error.

```
E:\java>javac Robot.java
Robot.java:16: error: illegal start of expression
public String CreateNew (); {
                       ^
Robot.java:16: error: ';' expected
public String CreateNew (); {
                       ^
2 errors
```

below is my program.

```
public class Robot {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String model;
        /*int year;*/
        String status;

        public String CreateNew () {
            Robot optimus;
            optimus = new Robot();
            optimus.model="Autobot"; 
            /*optimus.year="2008";*/
            optimus.status="active";
            return (optimus.model);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just as a side note it is usually a good idea to start methods lowercase while Classes have Capitalized names. Such is the Java convention

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to define a method (`CreateNew`) *within* a method (`main`), which you cannot do in Java. Move it out of the `main`; and as `model` and `status` appear to be instance variables (not method variables), move them as well:

```
public class Robot {
    // Member variables
    String model;
    /*int year;*/
    String status;

    // main method
    public static void main(String args[]){

        // Presumably more stuff here
    }

    // Further method    
    public String CreateNew () {
        Robot optimus;
        optimus = new Robot();
        optimus.model="Autobot"; 
        /*optimus.year="2008";*/
        optimus.status="active";
        return (optimus.model);
    }
}
```

Based on its content, you may want `CreateNew` to be `static` (so it can be called via `Robot.CreateNew` rather than via a `Robot` instance). Like this:

```
public class Robot {
    // Member variables
    String model;
    /*int year;*/
    String status;

    // main method
    public static void main(String args[]){

        // Presumably more stuff here
    }

    // Further method    
    public static String CreateNew () {
    //     ^----------------------------- here's the change
        Robot optimus;
        optimus = new Robot();
        optimus.model="Autobot"; 
        /*optimus.year="2008";*/
        optimus.status="active";
        return (optimus.model);
    }
}
```

Used as

```
String theModel = Robot.CreateNew();
```

...although it's unclear to me why you want to create a `Robot` instance and then throw it away and just return the `model` instance member's value.

---

Somewhat off-topic, but the overwhelming convention in Java is that method names (static or instance) start with a lower-case letter, e.g. `createNew` rather than `CreateNew`.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Thanks, I missed that they were being used in `CreateNew`.

Comment: @Jeffrey if i need the main method in the same program how should i write this.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close your main method before you create the `CreateNew()` one. In fact I don't think you meant to have a main method in your Robot class, you should have only one main method for your whole program. And  your CreateNew should be a *constructor*:

```
public class Robot {
        String model;
        /*int year;*/
        String status;

        public Robot () {
            this.model="Autobot"; 
            this.status="active";
        }
    }
}
```

and then in another class that contains your main method (or it could be in the same class too):

```
public class OtherClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Robot optimus = new Robot(); // here you create an instance of your robot.
    }
}
```

then you can have a second constructor that takes in parameter the model and status like that:

```
public Robot (String m, Status s) {
        this.model=m; 
        this.status=s;
}
```

and finally in your main:

```
Robot prime = new Robot("aName", "aStatus");
```